# tic tac toe tile logic in javascript

Tags: javascript

Someone, please help me with this, there is no error but when I click on any tile, it is always 'X' that is shown inside the tile but as we all know the there should be toggling between 'X' and 'O' and I have written the logic for that but I don't know why always 'X' is showing, please help

Also, I have not written the logic for win/lose in javascript, I will write it later.

```js
let previousClick = 'O';

let Button1 = document.getElementById('b1');
let Button2 = document.getElementById('b2');
let Button3 = document.getElementById('b3');
let Button4 = document.getElementById('b4');
let Button5 = document.getElementById('b5');
let Button6 = document.getElementById('b6');
let Button7 = document.getElementById('b7');
let Button8 = document.getElementById('b8');
let Button9 = document.getElementById('b9');


function handleClick1() {

    if (Button1.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick === 'X') {
            Button1.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick === 'O') {
            Button1.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick2() {

    if (Button2.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick === 'X') {
            Button2.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick === 'O') {
            Button2.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick3() {

    if (Button3.innerText === '') {
        if (previousClick === 'X') {
            Button3.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick === 'O') {
            Button3.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick4() {

    if (Button4.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button4.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick == 'O') {
            Button4.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick5() {

    if (Button5.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button5.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick == 'O') {
            Button5.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick6() {

    if (Button6.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button6.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick == 'O') {
            Button6.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick7() {

    if (Button7.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button7.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick == 'O') {
            Button7.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick8() {

    if (Button8.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button8.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick == 'O') {
            Button8.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick9() {

    if (Button9.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button9.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
        if (previousClick == 'O') {
            Button9.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="b1" onclick="handleClick1()"></button>
        <button id="b2" onclick="handleClick2()"></button>
        <button id="b3" onclick="handleClick3()"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="b4" onclick="handleClick4()"></button>
        <button id="b5" onclick="handleClick5()"></button>
        <button id="b6" onclick="handleClick6()"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="b7" onclick="handleClick7()"></button>
        <button id="b8" onclick="handleClick8()"></button>
        <button id="b9" onclick="handleClick9()"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./logic.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can try running the program by clicking on 'Run code snippet' to understand what I want to say.

Comment: You have two `if` statements each time, the 2nd `if` **always** runs after the 1st and will reset the value. Use `else if` for each of the second `if`s.

Comment: Functions are used to avoid repetitive code. The snippet above has functions repeating the same. You might wanna generalize them by passing in an additional parameter.

Comment: I don't know what can I pass to make it short, please tell me

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ubrd5yz1/ check out this example, i refactored your code, you can compare it with your own

Comment: great I got it, actually, I am a beginner in js, that's why these types of problems are coming, thank you all

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion: Use a single function for the 9 handle clicks:
You can make a single click function:

```
<button onclick='click( id )' id='b + id'></button>
.
.
.
<!-- replace the id with a number for every button -->
<script>
    // js
    function click(id) {
        // click function 
        let btn = document.getElementById('b'+id);
        if (btn.innerHTML == '') {
            // select X or O
            // ternary operator
            btn.innerHTML = (previous=='X') ? 'O' : 'X'
            previous = btn.innerHTML
        }
    }
</script>
```

Basically what is happening here is that every button will pass its id to the function, to make it select the button itself. 
Then if the button is empty
Select the opposite of the previous. 
Then change the previous to the text on the btn.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

```js
let previousClick = 'O';

let Button1 = document.getElementById('b1');
let Button2 = document.getElementById('b2');
let Button3 = document.getElementById('b3');
let Button4 = document.getElementById('b4');
let Button5 = document.getElementById('b5');
let Button6 = document.getElementById('b6');
let Button7 = document.getElementById('b7');
let Button8 = document.getElementById('b8');
let Button9 = document.getElementById('b9');


function handleClick1() {

    if (Button1.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick === 'X') {
            Button1.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
       else{
            Button1.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick2() {

    if (Button2.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick === 'X') {
            Button2.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
         }
       else{
            Button2.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick3() {

    if (Button3.innerText === '') {
        if (previousClick === 'X') {
            Button3.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
       else{
            Button3.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick4() {

    if (Button4.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button4.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
      }
       else{
            Button4.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick5() {

    if (Button5.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button5.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
       else{
            Button5.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick6() {

    if (Button6.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button6.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
         }
       else{
            Button6.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick7() {

    if (Button7.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button7.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
       }
       else{
            Button7.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick8() {

    if (Button8.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button8.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
            }
       else{
            Button8.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
function handleClick9() {

    if (Button9.innerText == '') {
        if (previousClick == 'X') {
            Button9.innerText = 'O';
            previousClick = 'O';
        }
       else{
            Button9.innerText = 'X';
            previousClick = 'X';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="b1" onclick="handleClick1()"></button>
        <button id="b2" onclick="handleClick2()"></button>
        <button id="b3" onclick="handleClick3()"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="b4" onclick="handleClick4()"></button>
        <button id="b5" onclick="handleClick5()"></button>
        <button id="b6" onclick="handleClick6()"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="b7" onclick="handleClick7()"></button>
        <button id="b8" onclick="handleClick8()"></button>
        <button id="b9" onclick="handleClick9()"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./logic.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As *Peter B* said, you have to use `else if` in the code.

I created a single handler instead of 9, so decided that my solution worth posting anyway. Good luck!

```js
let previousClick = "O";
const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const target = e.target 
  if (target.tagName !== 'BUTTON' || target.innerText !== '') {
    return
  }
  
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (previousClick === "X") {
    target.innerText = "O";
    previousClick = "O";
  } else if (previousClick === "O") {
    target.innerText = "X";
    previousClick = "X";
  }
});
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      max-width: 300px;
      max-height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      margin-top: 20vh;
    }

    .row {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: auto;
    }
    button {
      border: 1px solid black;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 50px;
      background-color: red;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <button id="b1"></button>
            <button id="b2"></button>
            <button id="b3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button id="b4"></button>
            <button id="b5"></button>
            <button id="b6"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button id="b7"></button>
            <button id="b8"></button>
            <button id="b9"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src="./logic.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here has to do with a couple things:

1. where you are defining the previousClick variable
2. the overriding nature of your if statements

Each time the handleClicks are called, they load the same script. Therefore, because previousClick is defined as “O” in the same script as the functions, it is always going to be redefined as “O” before the function is executed. You should create a separate script above your body tag that defines the global previousClick variable (as a var or you can also define it on document.previousClick).

Second, since you are using two back to back if statements, if previousClick equals “X” it will run both statements, and the innerText will be reset to “X” immediately, leaving no possibility of displaying an “O”. Change the second “if” to an “else if” in each click function.